# C# Unit Testing - Should you unit test something in a derived class that is taken care of in a base class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public Foo(Bar bar)
    {
        if (bar == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("bar");
    }
}

public class Foo : Foo<Object>
{
    public Foo(Bar bar) : base(bar) { }
}
```

Basically, I understand that I should unit test the constructor for the Generic Foo. Should I also unit test the constructor for the non-generic version? The reason I ask is because the exception is being thrown at the generic constructor level...

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedExeption(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
public void GenericFooNullArgumentInConstructor()
{
    var foo = new Foo<int>(null);
}

//Is this test necessary?
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedExeption(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
public void NonGenericFooNullArgumentInConstructor()
{
    var foo = new Foo(null);
}
```

Comment: I would really like to see an authoritative view on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one word: Yes.
The key here is [regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_regression) - you'd write the unit tests to verify your current implementation (or even before implementation if you're TDD), but also you write it to protect yourself from breaking changes of the code in the future.
Since both the base and the sub class may be changed in the future - both should be tested.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Without looking at all the implementations, that's the easiest way to verify that your derived classes have maintained the guarantees of your base class. Especially when Bob the intern comes in later and modifies your derived class to do something else.

Comment: Bob the intern should be required to test his code, and other developers should be responsible for reviewing his code. Writing unit tests will just confuse the matter later for when Bob writes something useful that doesn't pass the existing unit tests written for code that doesn't exist, and hasn't even been thought of yet.

Comment: @xixonia: Exactly what unit tests are for. If Bob does break some unit test, he (or others on the team with more knowledge) will evaluate if what he did is the correct behaviour. If the new behaviour breaks some old assumptions, then modify the existing unit tests to conform to the new assumptions.

Comment: Unit tests are for testing code, not for testing people. If some code changes, the changer of the code should write/modify the corresponding unit tests according to the requirements he is coding to. If he doesn't, he's not doing his job. Imagine having 10 methods on a base class with 10 unit tests each, and having 10 classes derive from that class. Those classes have 5 levels of class hierarchy each. 10x10x10x5 = 5000 unit tests to test 10 simple methods. Now add a class. Now add another one.

Comment: @xixonia: Of course your mileage may vary. As with all things in our industry, there are tradeoffs. But it still helps to have a "paranoid" approach. I'm working on a project with a similar class hierarchy. And no we do not have ~5000 test methods. We do not duplicate our test methods for each concrete type. But if 5000 unit tests fazes you, look at [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/testing.html). They have **millions** of test cases.

Comment: @xixonia: Okay. "Similar class heirarchy" is an exaggeration. But my point is that one can adopt a strategy to avoid duplicate test methods for derived classes.

Comment: Sure you can be paranoid, or you can adopt good procedure, and good development practices... like TDD (writing unit tests for code you intend to write), and Code Reviews (reviewing code and the corresponding unit tests that someone else has written). Writing unit tests for something that *might* exist in the future is just wasting time.

Comment: And yes, you *can* adopt a strategy to avoid duplicate test methods for derived classes. It's called not duplicating test methods.

Answer (score 2):

***It depends...***

why are you writing unit tests?

1) to test the code you are about to write

2) to test the code you have already written

3) to test the code someone might write in the future

If you're writing code to test something you're about to write, write it for the requirements of the code you're going to write.

If you're writing tests to test your code, test the code you write.

If your writing tests to prevent other people from changing your code, that's not your responsibility.

**Example**

You have a base class A with a particular method, M. You have tested this method backwards, sideways, and upside down. You then create 3 subclasses of A, and call them B, C, and D. You add new functionality inner methods for class B and C.

You should test the new methods of class B and C, because this code is untested, but the method M from class A is already tested.

You override method M in class D, add code, and then call the base method M. The new override method should be tested, and it must be treated as an entirely new method. The unit test has no way to confirm that the base class's M method has been called.

Writing the same test 4 times doesn't do anyone any good. Each developer should be rewriting tests for the code they write. If that code is tested, and the tests meet requirements, and the tests pass, then the code is good.

Taking the same exam three times in a row is pointless.

**On the other hand**

We don't live in a perfect world, and if you have a problem with other developers *not* testing their own code, then you may find it useful to do their job for them. But do realize, it's not your job to test the code they write, that's their job.

**Super late update...**

You should also test methods *which will be directly effected by* the new code you are writing. For instance, if you *do not* change method A, but method A *relies on* method B, and you *override* method B, you should consider testing method A in your derived class, since the functionality of method A may have been changed due to it's dependence on method B.

Comment: As an appendix to my own answer, I believe that while the thoughts portrayed here are valid, I don't believe they answer the question in the most direct fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You should write unit tests for the derived class too! Unit tests ensures you that the tested class works as you expect it. That gives you the chance to refactor it some day. If then you'll make a mistake while refactoring the constructor of the derived class - no unit test will find that error. (If you haven't wrote unit tests for the derived class).

Comment: "That gives you the chance to refactor it some day." why not just test the code when your refactor it?

Comment: There are two different approaches. The first one is called TDD (Test driven development). At the beginning you plan your interfaces and classes, then you write the tests and after that you implement the classes. The second approach is the claim to ensure your code is running correctly. You write test to verify that.

Comment: Sure but neither of those scenarios have anything to do with writing tests for code you don't intend to write.